# What is the probability distribution of slots with x number of objects after m placements of n choose k permutations without repetition?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, permutations

**Problem**

I have 1000 slots.

I first randomly place 20 balls in the 1000 slots.
I can only place one ball per slot (no repetition).

I then randomly place 40 additional balls in the same 1000 slots.
I can only place one ball per slot (no repetition), but I *can* place a ball in a slot that already has a ball from a previous placement.

I repeat the process $m$ times.

**Question(s)**

- n = number of slots
- k = number of objects per placement
- m = number of placements
- x = number of balls in a given slot

I want to know the probability distribution of the slots that have $x$ number of balls after $m$ placements.
(e.g, What's the probability of having 2 slots with 4 balls after 4 placements of 10, 30, 50, and 60 balls in 300 slots? What is the probability of having 6 slots with 2 balls after 2 placements? etc.).

Is there a formula for it?

**Reasoning**

Each placement is a permutation without repetition of n choose k objects, where n is the number of slots and k is the number of balls.
$$\frac{n!}{(n − k)!}$$
That means that at any given placement, the probability of any one slot to end up with a ball in it is $\frac{k}{n}$.

So for example, after 3 placements of 10,20, and 30 balls in 100 slots, the probability of an individual slot of containing $x$ balls is the following (or so I think):

$$ P(0) =(1-\frac{10}{100}) * (1- \frac{20}{100}) * (1- \frac{30}{100})$$
$$  P(1) = ((\frac{10}{100}) * (1- \frac{20}{100}) * (1- \frac{30}{100})) + ((1-\frac{10}{100}) * (\frac{20}{100}) * (1- \frac{30}{100})) + ((1-\frac{10}{100}) * (1- \frac{20}{100}) * (\frac{30}{100}))$$
$$ P(2) = ((\frac{10}{100}) * ( \frac{20}{100}) * (1- \frac{30}{100})) + ((1-\frac{10}{100}) * (\frac{20}{100}) * (\frac{30}{100})) + ((\frac{10}{100}) * (1- \frac{20}{100}) * (\frac{30}{100}))$$
$$ P(3) = (\frac{10}{100}) * (\frac{20}{100}) * (\frac{30}{100})$$

$$ P(0) + P(1) + P(2) + P(3) = 1$$

So, in this example:

$$P(3) = 0.006$$
$$P(2) = 0.082$$
$$P(1) = 0.398$$
$$P(0) = 0.504$$

This means that on average 50 slots would be empty (cause there are only 60 balls but 100 slots, obv), 40 would be filled with 1 ball, 8 with 2 balls, and 1 with 3 balls.

Each of those probabilities has its own underlying distribution, both upper and lower limited in each case (eg, there cannot be less than 40 slots with no balls, and no more than 70).

What's more, the distributions are not independent of each other.

How do I model the process in a multivariate probability distribution?

Comment: I have an answer to all but one of your questions.  However, I am not allowed to
share my answer unless you edit your query to show work.  This means, sharing
your thoughts about what the answer might be, consulting definitions and trying
to find an answer, and then placing all of this directly into your query.
After you have done that, if no one else steps up, address a comment to @user2661923
and I will give my answer.  ...see next comment

Comment: "Can it be generalized to n distinct placements instead of just 2?"
Unsure what is being asked here.  
If you are asking about having (for example) exactly 17 slots that contain 1 red ball
and 1 blue ball, that is included in my answer.  Alternatively, are you asking 
about having a match represent 2 blue balls in the same slot as 1 red ball (for example), 
with one of the original restrictions changed?  If so, I need a very explicit specification 
for how many blue balls can go into the same slot.

Comment: @user2661923
Thank you for your comment. I've updated the query and shown where I'm stuck.
I think my reasoning is correct cause the numbers add up, but I can't abstract it to a general model, nor understand how to create the probability distribution.

Comment: answer given.  you won't like my answer, but you won't be bored.

Comment: @user2661923
Thank you for your answer. It is definitely helpful. Unfortunately, my understanding and intuition of probability and combinatorics are stuck at a junior-high level at best, so I cannot imagine going much further than you. In any case, I'll continue investigating. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This response can **in no way** be construed as an answer.  I am providing it
in an *answer* slot, simply for legibility.  In fact, if anyone else had
answered your query, I would not have given any response, except perhaps an
offhand comment.

I am way out of my depth here.  Any **answer** that I give would be **suspect** because
I couldn't be sure of my analysis.  The temptation is for me to apply the
principle of Linearity of Expectation, as discussed at
https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/.

However, it takes
serious experience before someone develops their **math intuition** to the point
that they know what they are doing for this type of problem.  The person would
have to have a deep understanding of the theory behind "linearity of expectation".
I lack this experience, I lack the understanding, and I lack the developed intuition.

I am going to confine my response to a very simple scenario that will illustrate
why I can not give an answer with any confidence.

Suppose that you have 100 slots. 
Suppose that you are going to have 2 placements. 
In the first placement, you will distribute 20 balls. 
In the second placement you will distribute 30 balls.

Consider the following two **distinct** questions.

(Q1) 
What is the number of ways of having exactly $n$ slots out of the 100, where
these $n$ slots, and only these $n$ slots have two balls in them (at the end
of the 2 placements), where $n \in \{0, 1, 2, \cdots, 20\}.$

This question roughly parallels the 1st question that you posed in your
original query.

(Q2) 
What is the expected number of slots that will have $x$ balls in them, after
two placements, where $x \in \{0, 1, 2\}.$

This question provides an **extremely simple** version of the question that
your query is now posing.

---

(Q1) 
In this problem **only** (not Q2), you can make the simplifying assumption that
the 1st placement placed a ball in each of slots 1-20, inclusive.
This assumption is made simply to make it easier to **visualize the analysis**.

Then, the # of different ways that the 30 balls can be distributed among the
100 slots is

$$ D = \binom{100}{30}. $$

The number of ways that the 30 balls can be distributed so that $n$ of them
are distributed in the 1st $20$ slots, and $(30 - n)$ of them are distributed
in the last 80 slots is

$$N(n) = \binom{20}{n} \times \binom{100 - 20}{30 - n}.$$

So the chances of exactly $n$ matches will be

$$\frac{N(n)}{D}.$$

---

Q(2) 
Let $p_1$ denote the chance that a slot receives a ball during the 1st placement. 
Let $p_2$ denote the chance that a slot receives a ball during the 2nd placement. 
Then, $p_1 = \frac{20}{100} = \frac{1}{5}$ and $p_2 = \frac{30}{100} = \frac{3}{10}$. 
Let $q_1 = (1 - p_1)$ and let $q_2 = (1 - p_2).$

**Superficially**, in accordance with what seems to be indicated by the
"Linearity of Expectation" article, one might reason as follows.

The chance that a specific slot has 0 balls after two placements is 
$(q_1 \times q_2).$

The chance that a specific slot has 1 ball after two placements is 
$(p_1 \times q_2) + (p_2 \times q_1).$

The chance that a specific slot has 2 balls after two placements is
$(p_1 \times p_2).$

You are then **supposed** to reason that there are 100 slots, so the expected number of
slots with 0 balls in them after two placements is 
$100 \times (q_1 \times q_2).$

Similarly, you are then supposed to reason that the expected number of slots with
1 ball in them after two placements is 
$100 \times \left[ ~(p_1 \times q_2) + (p_2 \times q_1) ~\right].$

Similarly, you are then supposed to reason that the expected number of slots with
2 balls in them after two placements is 
$100 \times (p_1 \times p_2).$

For all I know, the above results might actually be accurate; I simply don't
know.  Here is what concerns me.

Let's suppose that we are examining the situation where the 1st slot did **not**
have any balls in it, after the two placements.  Then, it becomes **slightly
more likely than normal** that the 2nd slot receives 1 or 2 balls.

This means that if you construe each of the 100 slots as an Event that may receive
0, 1, or 2, balls, then the 100 separate events are **not** independent events.

My **very brief** skim of https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/
*suggests* that the answers I have **guessed at** for Q2 **might be** accurate.

---

Now consider an alteration of Q2, where there are 3 placements instead of 2,
and in the third placement, 40 balls will be distributed among the 100 slots.

**Very superficially**, one might surmise that analysis that paralleled the
analysis in Q2 above should be repeated, despite the fact that the inter-related
dependence of the events is even more complex.

Not only is it unclear **to me** whether the analysis that I gave in Q2 is
valid, but **even assuming** that it is valid, it would **still be unclear**
to me whether the same type of analysis would be valid in this alteration of Q2.

Comment: @NeilPetz See also back and forth comments between sudix and me that followed his answer.

Answer (score 0):

In advance:
I'll answer your question only for the distribution which gives us the probability that in the first slot we have $c_1$ balls, in the second slot $c_2$, ... , in the $n$-th slot $c_n$ balls.

Furthermore it'll be a negative result - there is no formula, or even just efficient algorithm that gives us this (exact) probability distribution.

I can not proof that the same holds true for your actual question, but I suspect so.

---

We can see the problem as a series of $m$ sub-experiments, in each of which we pick $k_i$ of $n$ possible numbers.

Let
$$p_i:=p_i(A_i):=\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k_i}}$$

be the probability that in the $i$-th sub-experiment, we fill up exactly the slots $A_i:=(a_{i,1},...,a_{i,k_i})$. Note that the formula isn't actually dependent on the slots we fill up.

Now, the probability to fill in the first sub-experiment the slots $a_{1,1},...,a_{1,k_1}$, in the second the slots $a_{2,1},...,a_{2,k_2}$, ..., and in the last the slots $a_{m,1},...,a_{m,k_m}$, is then

$$\mathbb P (\{(A_1,...,A_m)\})= p_1(A_1)\cdots p_m(A_m) = p_1\cdots p_m$$

as all sub-experiment are independent each other. In this step we've also introduced a probability measure with sample space $\Omega:=\times_{i=1}^m \{S\subset \{1,..,n\}\mid |S|= k_i\}$.

Note further that two experiments (each having $m$ sub-experiments) that aren't completely equal, can not happen at the same time.

Now, what we want to know is: 
What is the probability that we have exactly $a_i$  balls in the $i$-th slot?

This is the event
$$E:= \{ (A_1,..,A_m)\in\Omega\mid \forall j\in [n]: \sum_{i=1}^m (A_i)_j= a_j  \}$$

And the probability of the event then is $\mathbb P (E) = |E|\cdot p_1\cdots p_m$.

One might now try to work out $|E|$, but in the current formalism this would be quite a chore, so let's move to another formalism:

Any event/experiment that can occur can be described by an $m\times n$ matrix which only has 0's and 1's, and for which the $i$-th row sums to $k_i$. This is the set
$$
\Omega':=\{M\in \mathbb F_2\mid \forall i\in \{1,...,m\}: \sum_{j=1}^n M_{i,j} = k_i\}
$$

I.e. every one in this matrix in cell $(i,j)$ tells us that in the $i$-th sub-experiment, we put a ball in the $j$-th slot.
Therefore, every row has exactly $k_i$ slots that are filled with a ball , and the column sums tell us how many balls are in each slot.

Since each element $\omega\in\Omega$ corresponds to exactly one element $\omega'\in\Omega'$ we have that $\mathbb P(\omega ) =\mathbb P(\omega' ) = p_1\cdots p_m$.

So now we can, just as before, count the number of elements $\omega'\in\Omega'$ which have exactly $a_i$  balls in the $i$-th slot.

That is the following subset of  $\Omega'$:
$$
\{M\in \mathbb F_2\mid \left(\forall i\in \{1,...,m\}: \sum_{j=1}^n M_{i,j} = k_i\right)\land\left(\forall j\in \{1,...,n\}: \sum_{i=1}^n M_{i,j} = a_j\right)\}
$$

Counting this subset is a popular problem. The proof that counting the elements in this subset is #P-hard can be found in [this](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291098-2418%28199707%2910%3A4%253C487%3A%3AAID-RSA4%253E3.0.CO%3B2-Q) paper.

While exactly counting will therefore take exponential time (in e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^m k_i$), there are many approximation schemes or approximations (most of which are however, elaborate, and only work under certain assumptions).

Keywords to search for may be:

- Counting Binary Matrices with Given Row and Column Sums
- 0-1-Matrices with prescribed row and column sums
- Binary Contingency Table

Comment: It seems to me that you are much more knowledgeable than I am in this area.  I am very curious; just how thin was the ice beneath my *answer*?

Comment: @user2661923 In stochastic/combinatoric, the ice is always thin. People unknowingly make assumptions, a single step often contains lots of transformations, many of which are based on intuition. At the same time, human intuition in these disciplines isn't all to trustworthy. That said, both your (Q1) and (Q2) seem correct both in logic and in  execution (though in the end, the best way to make sure, is to numerically test them). (Q2) can, as you correctly guessed, easily be extended, even to the general case. The thin ice would have been in any attempt to generalize the formula for (Q1),